# how does word variety depend on total words?

Tags: nlp

I want to compare the word variety of several books. But some are short, while others are long. So how can I correct for the fact that longer books will generally contain a larger number of unique words. I tried simply dividing the number of unique words in each book by the number of total words in each book. But I think that was overdoing it, because now the shorter books appear to have the most variety. What is the best approach to this?

Comment: How do you define unique? If its only words that show up once in the document, wouldn't shorter books have a higher number of unique words?

Comment: no, by unique i don't mean shows up once in the document. by unique i mean this string has five unique words: " sam is happy. sam is angry. sam is hungry."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simple answer is to use a sample of equal size from every book, or even better to randomly extract several samples of equal size from every book and then use the mean across samples.

> I tried simply dividing the number of unique words in each book by the number of total words in each book

This is known as the type/token ratio, the simplest way to measure [lexical density](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexical_density). I think it makes perfect sense in the case you describe, as far as I know usually it's not too biased.